# Undefined color `azure3' - colors defined by tabularray

Tags: color, tabularray

I found out that all the colors that are used in the examples of tabularray are not defined by xcolor. I can use these colors in the document, but not in the preamble.

What exactly does tabularray do and how can I make these colors available also before the document.

This fails

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\colorlet{newcolor}{azure3}

\begin{document}
    \color{azure3} Hello.
\end{document}
```

with

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `azure3'.
                                                
l.5 \colorlet{newcolor}{azure3}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}` and I think it's `Azure3`, not `azure3`. (Not checked)

Comment: @Rmano I have verified it is perfect your comment.

Comment: Azure3 is definey by xcolor, but that is a completely different color than the one defined by tabularray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabularray checks at the start of the document if the xcolor package is loaded and if yes it will automatically load the `ninecolors` package, which defines `azure3` (amongst others).

According to the tabularray documentation, this is done for proper color contrast.

Here the relevant part of the tabularray source:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}{\RequirePackage{ninecolors}}{}
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{
    \newenvironment{tblrNoHyper}{\NoHyper}{\endNoHyper}
  }{
    \newenvironment{tblrNoHyper}{}{}
  }
}
```

Comment: So the solution is to load package `ninecolors` in the preamble to have the colors available directly.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech yes